# How to get model attributes in scikit learn (not hyper parameters)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, clustering

How to get model attributes list (not hyper parameters passed to Estimator's class)?

For ex:

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=5) 
kmeans.fit(X)
kmeans.labels_
```

how to get list of the attributes like labels_ from model object (ending with _)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access *"labels_"* before fitting the data.

```py
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)

def get_properies(model):   
  return [i for i in model.__dict__ if i.endswith(‘_’)] 

get_properies(kmeans)
```

> *['n_clusters',
> 'init',
> 'max_iter',
> 'tol',
> 'precompute_distances',
> 'n_init',
> 'verbose',
> 'random_state',
> 'copy_x',
> 'n_jobs',
> 'algorithm',
> 'cluster_centers_',
> 'labels_',
> 'inertia_',
> 'n_iter_']*

Answer (score 1):

When ever you fit the model (let say regression )

```
model.fit(x,y)
```

To get model parameters you can try

```
model.params_
```

This gives the values of  b0,b1 in y=b0+b1*x

Answer (score 0):

you can find the list of an algorithm's attributes from the sklearn page for the corresponding algorithm.

For Kmeans:

```
Attributes

cluster_centers_ :ndarray of shape (n_clusters, n_features)
Coordinates of cluster centers. If the algorithm stops before fully converging (see tol and max_iter), these will not be consistent with labels_.

labels_ :ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
Labels of each point

inertia_ :float
Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center.

n_iter_ :int
Number of iterations run.
```

Reference: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is how to find the attributes of a model (parameters are the ones used to tune the model).

You can find the Model attributes from the Scikit-learn documentation of that model in the Attributes section.

Attributes for K-Means:

- cluster_centers_: ndarray of shape (n_clusters, n_features)
  Coordinates of cluster centres. If the algorithm stops before fully converging (see tol and max_iter), these will not be consistent with labels_.
- labels_: ndarray of shape (n_samples,)
  Labels of each point
- inertia_:
  Sum of squared distances of samples to their closest cluster center.
- n_iter_:
  The number of iterations run.